# find command + to search direcories

Tags: find

I used the following find command to search files

```
   find /tmp -regex ".*some_file"
```

How I can to search on the same way directories?

Yael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-type d` test:

```
find /tmp -type d -regex ".*some_dir"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp -regex ".*some_dir" -type d
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
find /tmp -regex "some_dir" -type d
```